# Getting a drawable using for loop index

Tags: java, android, loops

I am designing UI and for that need to populate some dummy content for recyclerview. So I thought to create using for loop so it makes life easier if I want to change the number.

I have drawable resources (images) that suffix with numbers. for instance

> avatar_1, avatar_2, avatar_3, ...
> featured_1, featured_2, featured_3, ...

I have tried setting `R.drwable.featured_ + i` and as expected it didn't work and end up with an error.

### This is what I am using

```
...

for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {

    int username = random.nextInt(userNames.length);
    int catInt   = random.nextInt(categories.length);
    int time     = random.nextInt(times.length);

    mBlogs.add(new Blog(
            R.drawable.featured_ + i, // this
            R.drawable.avatar_ + i, // this
            getString(R.string.blog_title),
            categories[catInt],
            getString(R.string.blog_excerpt),
            userNames[username],
            times[time],
            random.nextBoolean(),
            random.nextBoolean()
    ));
}

...
```

> **Question:** How can I get resource within the loop by loop index?

Comment: Why a negative vote? What is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Try as below.

```java
//find drawable resource id 
public int getDrawableId(Context context, String name) 
{
    try {
        return getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } 
}
```

```java
...
for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    int username = random.nextInt(userNames.length);
    int catInt   = random.nextInt(categories.length);
    int time     = random.nextInt(times.length);
    int featuredRes = getDrawableId(context, "featured_" + i);
    int avatarRes = getDrawableId(context, "avatar_" + i);

    // if not found any resource
    if (featuredRes == 0) featuredRes = R.drawable.featured_default

    if (avatarRes == 0) avatarRes = R.drawable.avatar_default

    mBlogs.add(new Blog(
            featuredRes,
            avatarRes,
            getString(R.string.blog_title),
            categories[catInt],
            getString(R.string.blog_excerpt),
            userNames[username],
            times[time],
            random.nextBoolean(),
            random.nextBoolean()
    ));
}
...
```

Comment: Although the logic is the same as @shb since your code looks more organized that reduce the code duplication. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getIdentifier`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    int featuredResId = getResources().getIdentifier("featured_" + i, "drawable", getPackageName())
    int avatarResId = getResources().getIdentifier("avatar_" + i, "drawable", getPackageName())
    //...
    mBlogs.add(new Blog(
            featuredResId,
            avatarResId,
            //...
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and reference code. I am unable to set `getPackageName()` it shows error `cannot resolve method`. For your reference, I am using this code in the fragment.

Comment: use getActivity().getPackageName()

Comment: Ah. I have to use `getActivity().getPackageName()`